# Firebase Messaging for Unity only showing default icon on notifications

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just updated Firebase Messaging to version 4.4, and now whenever I receive a notification, the icon it's using is a default android one.

Before, I used version 4.2 it worked fine sending the "icon" parameter with the message and it used the icon from my drawable folder (Assets/Plugins/Android/AN_Res/res/drawable).

I doesn't even use the default icon I have in AndroidManifest or the app icon that it usually would.

Have something changed in Firebase 4.4 or can someone help me figure out what I have to do to get it right? Firebase documentation doesn't seem to have anything on the subject.

cheers

/Jonas

Comment: Btw - just checked, the icon files are in the drawable folder inside the apk.

Comment: I've also tried sending from firebase console with same result

Comment: Also, posting the "color" parameter works fine

Answer (score 0):

After talking to firebase support, I found out it is a known bug in firebase, and it only occurs in Android O (8.0).

Here's the reply from firebase support:

> Thanks for reporting this to us.
>
> Could you confirm if this is only happening in Android O devices? If so, this is currently a known issue on our end and the team already has a fix ready, but I can't provide the exact date for its release. I suggest that you just keep an eye out on our release notes for any future updates.

Comment: Hey! Same issue here, did you find a temporary fix?

Comment: I downgraded firebase to 4.2

Comment: This seems to still be a problem in Firebase 5.0